# How to tell if websocket client used secured or not secured connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have a server that can handle websocket connections using "ws://" & "wss://" 
The "ws://" I use for local environments but I want to block it & raise a custom exception if someone is trying to connect that way to the production server.

```
import websocket
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://MY_ROUTE")
ws.connect("wss://MY_ROUTE")
```

How can I tell from my server which one is the secured one? 
The type of object I'm handling is `geventwebsocket.websocket.WebSocket`

Comment: Setting and using *environment variables* — that's typically how you give programs information about their running environment.

Comment: I know which environment I am but i don't know if the client used ws or wss to connect